# scanf causing an infinite loop and not returning -1 or EOF

Tags: c, scanf, infinite-loop

My program is supposed to read in integers from stdin and then

Examples:

Input File Contains:   `"3 1 4 2 5\n"`
Function Outputs: `"{3, 1, 4, 2, 5}\n"`

Input File Contains: `"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8\n"`
Function Outputs: `"{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}\n"`

Input File Contains: nothing (empty file)
Function Outputs: `"No integers were provided.\n"`

and this works fine with normal stdin until I try to read from a stdin redirection with a .txt file that looks like this

[input .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRCTh.png)

input.txt : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

and when running GDB I see this:

[My GDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkNGt.png)

and it keeps filling my integer array with 10 until my program crashes.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printNums() {
  int nums[100];
  int num;
  int count = 0;
  int x;
  if ((scanf("%d", &num)) == EOF) {
    printf("No integers were provided.\n");
    return;
  } else {
    nums[count] = num;
    count++;
  }
  while ((scanf("%d", &num) == 1)) {
    if (num != ' ') {
      nums[count] = num;
      count++;
    }
  }
  printf("{");
  for (x = 0; x < count; x++) {
    if (x == count - 1) {
      printf("%c", nums[x]);
    } else {
      printf("%c, ", nums[x]);
    }
  }
  printf("}\n");
}
```

Keep in mind that I am not allowed to import anything else other than stdio and it would be preferable to user scanf or getchar

Comment: It complies and runs fine for me. Did you make sure to remove the line numbers @usr2564301?

Comment: Look up  the `scanf` function to see what it returns.

Comment: Can you please edit your code to remove line numbers. Surely you have an option for that in your IDE.

Comment: @machine_1 done!

Comment: First of all I'd provide a sane boundary check on the `count` variable: `while (... && count < 100)`. If that condition is hit, it means the scanf() didn't find / return an EOF.

Comment: Comparing the return value of `scanf` with `EOF` or  `'\n'` makes very little sense.

Comment: @JohnColeman Indeed `scanf("%d", &num)` should return `1` on success or `anything < 1` on failure: https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

Comment: @usr2564301 sorry about that, fixed it!

Comment: From the image it looks like there is no \n at the end of the line, the file just ends, try adding one and see if it works then.

Comment: @MartinHennings I just edited my code and it still does not work, please take a look again :)

Comment: @JohnColeman I just edited my code, please take a look again.

Comment: Your latest code works (almost) perfectly for me.  I had to change `%c` to `%d` in your `printf` calls, and then it worked perfectly, whether reading from stdin or a file.

Comment: @user3194396 Your question doesn't show the stdin redirection. What command are you calling your program with?

Comment: @SteveSummit wow that was the solution! Can you please explain how that would make that big of a difference!

Comment: And did you really re-type all those numbers from those images?

Comment: @JohnColeman: The standard says [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) returns EOF (not `-1`, though it's the same thing when `EOF  == -1`, of course).  By contrast, POSIX says [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) returns `-1`, even on systems where `EOF != -1`.  You're right that EOF is only required to be negative, but it is overwhelmingly commonly `-1`.  But you should get the comparison right.

Comment: @user3194396 I doubt that was the solution.  You've been changing lots of things, right?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for an infinite loop is in the argument %d, which is a signed decimal integer, and not a character that you are entering. Yes, as @SteveSummit  noticed, and he should put it here as another answer, Using %c will resolve the problem. The root cause of the problem, I think, is in implicit newline character that is not consumed, when %d has been entered. %c does care about it.

Answer (score 0):

The code should work fine, except for incorrectly printing the numbers (use `%d` instead of `%c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printNums() {
  int nums[100];
  int num;
  int count = 0;
  int x;
  if ((scanf("%d", &num)) == EOF) {
    printf("No integers were provided.\n");
    return;
  } else {
    nums[count] = num;
    count++;
  }
  while ((scanf("%d", &num) == 1)) {
    if (num != ' ') {
      nums[count] = num;
      count++;
    }
  }
  printf("{");
  for (x = 0; x < count; x++) {
    if (x == count - 1) {
      printf("%d", nums[x]);
    } else {
      printf("%d, ", nums[x]);
    }
  }
  printf("}\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printNums();
}
```

I added a `main()` function, and compiled and invoked like this:

```
$> gcc -Wall -o count count.c
$> echo '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10' | ./count
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
$> echo '3 1 4 2 5' | ./count
{3, 1, 4, 2, 5}
$> echo -n '' | ./count
No integers were provided.
```

As you can see, it prints the expected output. Three comments:

1. Double check that you recompile the program after modifying it, and that you are executing/debugging the correct binary. It happens constantly.
2. How are you invoking the program and getting the input? Maybe you have a problem there.
3. The vector is not initialized, so expect some random numbers there, not necessarily meaningful.

**UPDATE:** Just saw the comment from [Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923896/steve-summit) about the `%d` in `printf()`. But that shouldn't cause an infinite loop, just printing crap characters instead of numbers. It would be a problem if the `%c` was in the `scanf()`, which is not.